# API/machine access for Gapminder data?

Tags: api, demographics, global

I'd like to be able to access the Gapminder files programmatically (e.g. via R or Python), but I can't find a way so far.

- Gapminder's [downloads page](http://www.gapminder.org/downloads/) offers a variety of tools and charts, but nothing for programmatic access (that I can tell)
- their [data page](http://www.gapminder.org/data/) is clicky.
- there's some [discussion of the possibility of an API on their community support page](https://getsatisfaction.com/gapminder/topics/gapminder_api_for_web_developers), but nothing concrete
- someone wrote a [Python app](https://github.com/edsfocci/gapminder-api), but I have to admit that I don't really understand how to use it (I have installed it, and can run `python3 app.py` after that, but that's as far as I get ..)
- [this web page](https://rdrr.io/cran/gapminder/api/) has a promising name, but it's a description of an R package that contains a little bit of downloaded Gapminder data

There's a nice R package [for accessing World Bank data](https://cran.r-project.org/package=wbstats) that overlaps with the data I want, but Gapminder seems to have stuff that isn't included in the WB database (e.g. GDP per capita 1950-1960).

... thoughts ... ?

Comment: What do you mean by "clicky"? Can't you dl everything you want in "Excel" format, convert, and use?

Comment: I want to be able to use a program to retrieve the values rather than going to the web page in a browser and doing it by hand ...

Comment: Oh, you could use a tool like "down-them-all" or something for mass downloading. Mass converting might be harder. Of course, you can always try contacting them directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded http://www.gapminder.org/data/ after choosing "ALL" and noticing the spreadsheet links end in "output=xlsx". I changed the xlsx to csv to see what would happen, and did, indeed, get CSV files as expected. More specifically, I ran:

`perl -nle 'while (s/href="(.*?)"//) {$x=$1; $x=~s/\&amp\;/&/g; print "curl -LO \47$x\47"}' gapminder.html | fgrep xlsx | sed 's/xlsx/csv/' | sh`

zipped the results, and uploaded them to https://www.dropbox.com/s/r77tfdjt1lzkn56/gapminder.zip?dl=0

The only problem is that 519 files I thus obtained have weird names, so you may need to figure out which file is which.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scraping this a little more thoroughly myself (including e.g. following redirects so the real Google sheets URLs are actually available).

- The scraping code is [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mpha_2019/gapminder_scrape.R) (GitHub pages; too long to post here)
- The assembled CSV file is [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mpha_2019/gapminder_index.csv): 519 rows, starting:

```
indicator,provider,category,subcategory,URL
"Adults with HIV (%, age 15-49)",Based on UNAIDS,Health,HIV,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kWH_xdJDM4SMfT_Kzpkk-1yuxWChfurZuWYjfmv51EA/pub?output=xlsx
Age at 1st marriage (women),Various sources,Population,,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xYQ08p5llwPR3ZK6h900LDd-J7WuXCv_FoPlksrj-eA/pub?output=xlsx
Aged 15+ employment rate (%),International Labour Organization,Work,Employment rate,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jsXSKnWgsXvjYyR-4R2b9VKGh22IM70C9WQg74xK8U8/pub?output=xlsx
Aged 15+ labour force participation rate (%),International Labour Organization,Work,Labour force participation,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GBTNLyaFV__Bcz81ex3nQw6W6THqzKkaF9jZcCYjHw/pub?output=xlsx
```

- I also posted a [CSV file listing countries and their corresponding regions](https://bbolker.github.io/mpha_2019/country_regions.csv), scraped from [Wikipedia](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_regional_classification).